# VS2010 Nuget Package manager console no accessible

Tags: nuget

I am using vs2010 and I want to access Nuget package management console.In project menu I have Manage Nuget Packages option but no option to access the console. I tried to reinstall Nuget but to no avail.
Any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to launch the console. Did you try reading the docs? http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: Sorry , I was looking under Projects menu.there is an option manage Nuget Packages.Under tools menu is where I need to look